# Find next cell contained in sibling row with querySelector

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to use `querySelector` to find the first cell in the NEXT row of a table.  So, starting from ROW 1, find the next TR element, and then find the first child TD element within that TR element.

However, when I write the CSS selector, it returns `null`.

My CSS selector syntax is:

```
"tr.row ~ tr td"
```

Here's a full working example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <script>
        function findRow()
        {
            var row1 = document.querySelector("tr.row");
            var targetCell = row1.querySelector("tr.row ~ tr td");
            alert(targetCell);
        }
    </script>

</head>

<body>

    <table>
        <tr class = "row">
            <td class = "cell"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class = "row">
            <td class = "cell"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <script>
        findRow();
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

So the selector `".row1` successfully gives me the TR element with id `row1`.

However, the second selector, `".row1 ~ tr td"`, returns `null`.

Now, if instead of calling `querySelector` using the `TR` element, I call `document.querySelector`, it works.  I can even call `row1.parentNode.querySelector`, and then it works as well.  This indicates to me that the actual Element which *calls* `querySelector` is *not* included in the set of elements to be searched.

Unfortunately, that is not a solution here.  This is just a simplified example : in my actual use-case, I can't call `querySelector` from a parent element above `row1`, because then I will lose the context I'm in - (in my real use case I have many, dynamically-generated rows, so if I call `document.querySelector`, or even `row1.parentNode.querySelector` I'll lose my context).

I realize I can just do this with plain DOM traversal loops, but I'm trying to get in the habit of using `querySelector` here, since that is obviously better for the future.  (Also, I'm not using jQuery here.)  I also suspect the `:scope` selector would help here, but unfortunately that is not yet widely supported.

So it is possible to do what I want using `querySelector`?

Comment: would you consider using `nth-child` everywhere?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It will be difficult using `querySelector`. The problem with element.querySelector is that is only targets descendant nodes. Better use something like

```js
var targetCell = row1.nextElementSibling.cells[0];
```

```js
var row1 = document.querySelector("tr.row"),
    targetCell = row1.nextElementSibling.cells[0];
alert(targetCell);
```

```html
<table>
  <tr class="row">
    <td class="cell"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="row">
    <td class="cell"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

If you really want to use it, you can use `:nth-child(k)` on parent to reference the `k`th element.

```
var parent = row1.parentElement,
    index = [].slice.call(parent.children).indexOf(row1) + 1,
    targetCell = parent.querySelector(":nth-child("+index+") ~ tr td");
```

```js
var row1 = document.querySelector("tr.row"),
    parent = row1.parentElement,
    index = [].slice.call(parent.children).indexOf(row1) + 1,
    targetCell = parent.querySelector(":nth-child("+index+") ~ tr td");
alert(targetCell);
```

```html
<table>
  <tr class="row">
    <td class="cell"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="row">
    <td class="cell"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Added useful content from @pete's answer

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it's possible to target `#cell2` using `querySelector`, but you'll have to do it using `document.querySelector`, not `element.querySelector`.

The problem with `element.querySelector` is that is only targets *descendant* nodes, so sibling nodes (and their descendants) are right out. From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.querySelector):

> Returns the first element that is a descendant of the element on which it is invoked that matches the specified group of selectors.

Here's a fiddle showing the change: http://jsfiddle.net/usho2t63/

```
var targetCell = document.querySelector("#row1 ~ tr td");
```

Answer (score 1):

Since CSS selector cannot travel to parents, your best approach would be using DOM methods, as already answered by Oriol.

Alternativelly, using only `querySelector`, if you are sure to give every element an id you'd have to do something like this:

```
document.querySelector("#" + row1.getAttribute("id") + " ~ tr td");
```

to ensure you are always targeting the referenced row